# How to remove the first 50 items in a list without copying it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a very large list, and I'd like to iteratively remove the first 50 elements without copying it (as for example something like `list[50:]`).

My initial thought was by doing:

```
[list.pop(0) for i in range(50)]
```

What would be the most performant way to do this?

Comment: If you remove 50 elements from the front, you *will* copy the list, either implicitly or explicitly.  Why do you have to do it iteratively, rather than the straightforward and faster ways?

Comment: @Prune I see, how do you know it copies the list in-place?

Comment: The most performant way is to just *ignore* the first 50 elements. Is it possible that you do that? Or maybe you need a different data structure, which allows to efficiently remove items from the front, like a deque?

Comment: @mkrieger1 well I need to shuffle the list after each removal, that's why.

Comment: Are you trying to select 50 elements randomly from the list?

Comment: Research storage allocation for Python sequences.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, and then remove those items that were selected. But to make it a bit easier to keep track of, I just grab/pop the first 50 items, process those, then re-shuffle.

Comment: @Prune thanks. Do you have links to provide or suggested resources/comments, or is this the generic "read the docs/google it/research X" comment?

Comment: Yes, it's the generic research statement.  Asking for resources or references is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `del` keyword. So to remove the first 50 elements you can do:

```py
del list[:50]
```

Answer (score 3):

Update the list in place with a slice that removes the first 50 items:

```
list[:] = list[50:]
```

**Update**

I ran some timeit tests which actually show `del list[:50]` to be approx 2X faster.

Comment: great, want to show the `timeit`s and I can accept this.